# Windows IoT advice: One headed app or headless plus headed?

Tags: .net, uwp, headless, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

My main requirement is for an application which will run at all times, logging and submitting data to a cloud service. If a user happens to plug in a display device, it should should some basic status information and allow a few commands to be invoked.

Option 1: Deploy a single headed app containing all the logic and UI. When the display is unplugged (95% of the time), the UI will simply be ignored.

Option 2: Deploy all of the core logic in a background app which also exposes an app service.  A separate application would be responsible for the GUI only, surfacing data from the app service and passing through any commands initiated by the user.

Are there any advantages to option 2? Could it result in lower power consumption or higher availability with the display is unplugged?

Comment: For power consumption, you may need to do some tests. And for your usage(UI is ignored in 95% of the time) why not to use [headless mode](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/headlessmode) and expose your user interface in a website?

Comment: I guess a website could makes sense for a device which is on a LAN, but that is not the case here. The idea is that the display can be plugged in just to check the status locally, with the option of making minor config changes.

I guess you are right that I will just have to test for power consumption and that it probably won't make much difference.

More important is whether a headless app is more or less likely to be deactivated by the OS when if it thinks its running out of resources.

Comment: Background Applications have no limitations of the background task. Note that [you must call the “GetDeferral” method to prevent the application from exiting](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/backgroundapplications).